# What is geometry(4326), and can you do Cartesian calculations with unprojected ellipsoidal coordinates?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, geometry, geography-data-type, mysql-spatial

I know `Geography(4326)` is an unbounded, and unprojected, and covers the entire world with ellipsoidal coordinates. I get that the math on this system is done on a spheroid. I also get that with a `geometry` the math is done on a Cartesian grid. What I really would like to understand is how SRS 4326 can be subject to **both** ellipsoidal calculations, and Cartesian calculations without reprojection  (like `ST_Transform`)?

```
SELECT ST_Distance( ST_MakePoint(0,0)::geography, ST_MakePoint(1,1)::geography );
   st_distance   
-----------------
 156899.56829134
(1 row)

-- same result as ST_MakePoint(x,y)::geography::geometry
-- same result as ST_SetSRID( ST_MakePoint(x,y)::geometry, 4326 )
-- same result as ST_SetSRID( ST_MakePoint(x,y), 4326 )
SELECT ST_Distance( ST_MakePoint(0,0)::geometry, ST_MakePoint(1,1)::geometry );
   st_distance   
-----------------
 1.4142135623731
(1 row)
```

By extension, MySQL does **not** support nearly the amount of Geographic operations as PostGIS. Worse, it determines the type of calculation (geometric vs geographic) based not the type (as with PostGIS's `geometry` vs `geography`) but based merely as the SRS ID marker. For any operations that do not support a geodetic reference system, you have to use a Cartesian reference system (which is obviously major suck because MySQL can't reproject). But why if it has these two shortcomings (fewer geodetic calculations), and an inability to reproject can it not do a geometric calculation (Cartesian reference system) with SRS ID 4326? Lastly, is there any SRS ID that is **not** geodetic that behaves like PostgreSQL `geometry` type in SRS ID 4326, so I can use it with MySQL?

Comment: I started with an answer, but surrendered to it becoming a beast... anyway, consider the `GEOGRAPHY` type in PostGIS to be 'only' a container for the implied ellipsoidal math; it is **no projection** and its use not limited to a single **geodetic datum** (e.g. *WGS84 - EPSG:4326*). if a geographic CRS is used in a cartesian context, its units (degree of Lon/Lat) are projected as if they were planar units, with parallels of constant distance, leaving this 'projection' (*Equirectangular* - *Plate Carée*) heavily distorted and useless for anything analytical (neither conformal nor equal area).

Comment: ...but you can do cartesian algebra on it just fine. useless and with dangerously misleading results, but possible ,)

Comment: Interesting to see that the [PostGIS documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography) says `One restriction is that it only supports WGS 84 long lat (SRID:4326).`  because `4326` is a code of the EPSG database, and EPSG:4326 is lat lon.

Comment: @mmtoken *"Prior to PostGIS 2.2, the geography type only supported WGS 84 long lat (SRID:4326). For PostGIS 2.2 and above, any long/lat based spatial reference system defined in the spatial_ref_sys table can be used. You can even add your own custom spheroidal spatial reference system as described in "Geography type is not limited to earth." "* - [current docs](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography).

Comment: I did a lot of beta testing of MySQL spatial functions a few  years back, see, http://www.lenzg.net/archives/2009/07.html. I quickly realized that MySQL's focus was elsewhere and once Oracle took over, they were never going to promote an open source version of something that would compete with Oracle Spatial. So, I did the sensible thing and switched to Postgres/Postgis. You could always rewrite proj4 as MySQL functions :D.

Comment: @ThingumaBob Bounding boxes and intersections would be right, less the curvature of the Earth? For something like MySQL that would be super useful. So the question remains -- *"SRS ID that is not geodetic that behaves like PostgreSQL geometry type in SRS ID 4326, so I can use it with MySQL?"* Ie., without reprojecting (because you can't in MySQL).

Comment: In your 2nd example, the geometry doesn't have a defined CRS so the software has to assume that it's in a projected CRS and treat is cartographically. It doesn't know the unit either so 1.4142 could be in meters, inches, km...

Comment: Well, let's say it's in 4326. `ST_SetSRID( ST_MakePoint(x,y), 4326 )`

Comment: @EvanCarroll yes, topology ([DE-9IM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM)) is preserved! spatial relations/measurements with unit dependency (e.g. `ST_Distance`) will be distorted and/or useless; you can treat cartesian EPSG:4326 geometries as with a planar projection with heavy unit measure distortion.